# Fix Go commands all giving "go: error loading module requirements"?

Tags: go, go-modules

I am trying to install the dependencies for a Go project that uses Go modules. I have `GO111MODULES=on` in my environment.

No matter what command I run (`go build`, `go get`, `go clean --modcache`, ...) it fails with output something like:

```
sdgluck$ go build .
go: finding cloud.google.com/go v0.26.0
go: cloud.google.com/go@v0.26.0: unknown revision refs/tags/v0.26.0
go: error loading module requirements
```

The last line seems to appear in the output for every command, alongside some mention of `cloud.google.com/go`.

How can I fix this and just get Go to install the modules for this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in a comment below, the proper command to clear the Go modules cache is `go clean -modcache` (just one dash).

If that still doesn't work then you can try manually clearing your Go `mod` folder.

For example, if your GOPATH was `/Users/spongebob/go`:

```sh
rm -rf /Users/spongebob/go/pkg/mod
```

Comment: The proper way to clean the module cache is `go clean -modcache`.

Comment: `rm -rf …/pkg/mod` no longer works reliably, since Go by default marks the subdirectories readonly (unless overridden by `GOFLAGS=-modcacherw`). You’d have to first `chmod -R u+w …/pkg/mod` before you can run `rm -rf …`. Or use `go clean -modcache` as mentioned.